# Using a custom slice layer in caffe without knowing the size of 'top' until runtime?

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

Is this possible with caffe?  As far as I can tell, both setup and reshape are run without knowledge of the data.  My custom slice layer (a Python layer) aims to pick smart pairs "on the fly" for siamese training.  However, the class distribution varies slightly between each minibatch.

I am trying to implement this as a Python layer of the form:

```py
<!-- language: lang-py -->
class custom_slice_layer(caffe.Layer):
  def setup(self, bottom, top):
    # check top, bottom blobsvecs match desired size.

  def reshape(self, bottom, top):
    # reshape to the right size?  This is The error happens during the reshape step.

  def forward(self, bottom, top):
    # pick desired pairs for siamese training (to be fed into the default contrastive loss layer)

  def backward(self, top, propagate_down, bottom):
    # combine the gradients for backprop
```

Somewhat understandably, I currently get this error when running:

```
I0509 09:21:46.434281 14750 net.cpp:122] Setting up custom_slice_name
I0509 09:21:46.434306 14750 net.cpp:129] Top shape: (0)
I0509 09:21:46.434312 14750 net.cpp:129] Top shape: (0)
I0509 09:21:46.434319 14750 net.cpp:129] Top shape: (0)
I0509 09:21:46.434324 14750 net.cpp:137] Memory required for data: 790788800
I0509 09:21:46.434332 14750 layer_factory.hpp:77] Creating layer contrastiveloss
I0509 09:21:46.434350 14750 net.cpp:84] Creating Layer contrastiveloss
I0509 09:21:46.434360 14750 net.cpp:406] contrastiveloss <- ip2A
I0509 09:21:46.434370 14750 net.cpp:406] contrastiveloss <- ip2B
I0509 09:21:46.434377 14750 net.cpp:406] contrastiveloss <- sim
I0509 09:21:46.434387 14750 net.cpp:380] contrastiveloss -> contrastive_loss
F0509 09:21:46.434793 14750 blob.hpp:122] Check failed: axis_index < num_axes() (0 vs. 0) axis 0 out of range for 0-D Blob with shape (0)
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
Abort (core dumped)
```

Comment: make `reshape` and `setup` use some default values (based on default `bottom` shape they get). Do not forget to do the actual reshaping at `forward`.

Comment: I will gives this a shot.  thanks!